# Webpack generate multiple CSS loaders

Tags: internet-explorer-9, webpack, css-loader

I'm using WebPack to load all of my CSS rules into an application through the style-loader.  This seems to be working in most browsers, but this project has to support legacy browsers (namely IE9) which can only support a total of 4095 selectors per document.  We have a total of 10-11k.  This is mostly because all of our less rules combine down to one master document.  Think of how Twitter Bootstrap compiles their less files down with one main file.

Does anyone know of a way to have WebPack produce multiple chunks that would not break IE9 by chunking out to 4095 selectors per document?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Note that I haven't used it myself, but it looks like https://github.com/BlessCSS/bless-webpack-plugin might solve this.

Comment: Any chance of this working with the style-loader plugins?